# how to print Summery info to the report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I need to print summery info like revision No. from her ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUJW8.jpg ) to my report . (Crystal report 2008 )

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUJW8.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a windows folder as a data source, if you got an rpt inside you can get all that info:

1. Create a new connection
2. Search for File System Data ( should be on More Data Sources or something similar)
3. Choose the folder that contains your report

Then you can decide to include all files or filter to specific ones.

From there the folder becomes a table that you can use like you would any other table.

The field you required should be labeled "Revision Number (Summary Info)"

Comment: Thanks i need to gite information for one file but it not work well .